# Suspending application that have open menu freezes unix desktop

Tags: linux, unix, x11, xlib, suspend

I have this application that suspends applications when it rearch a certain cpu usage threshold. My problem now is when I suspend the application that currently have open menu, it freezes the whole Centos desktop. Is there a way to programmatically cancel open menus of applications before I suspend it?

My application is written in c++ so I can use xlib/x11, but I cant seem to cancel the menu of other application. I already used XRaiseWindow() and fake key events but still the menu is untouchable.

Comment: Why do you use a tool that suspends *interactive* GUI applications when they use the CPU? It looks wrong in the first place. If you wrote that tool, how does it suspend these? What about remote applications (e.g. a remote terminal started with `ssh -X -f remotehost xterm`)?

Comment: Did you take a lot of time to read [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer/question? I used `kill -stop <pid>`. Im a beginner in unix so I just wrote this app for experimentation. Im trying to suspend an application when it uses above 50% cpu usage then bumped into this scenario.

I havent read that yet, I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: Then don't suspend your application: either [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) it (if it is running locally!) it with `SIGTERM` (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)...) or use [setpriority(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpriority.2.html) like [renice(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html) would do.

Answer (score 0):

That's a known problem with X11. You cannot easily cancel menus of other applications. You however can check if a menu or similar item is active. To do so, call `XGrabKeyboard` and `XGrabPointer`. If both call succeeds, you can suspend your application. If not, call `XUngrabPointer` and `XUngrabKeyboard`, wait and try again. Always ungrab when you are done.

Sample code, try running it normally, then when a menu is active.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main ()
{
    Display* d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    int res = XGrabKeyboard(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);
    if (res == Success)
    {
        int res = XGrabPointer(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), True, 0, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);
        if (res == Success)
        {
            printf ("Grabbed!\n");
            // suspend app here
            XUngrabPointer(d, CurrentTime);
        }
        else
            printf ("Could not grab pointer\n");
        XUngrabKeyboard(d, CurrentTime);
    }
    else
        printf ("Could not grab keyboard\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but I cant ungrab the keyboard and pointer when the other application have open menu. I even tried putting it on while loop so it can wait and try again but still, the menu stays on top.

Comment: You cannot break the grab without killing the application. That's the point.

Comment: What about I minimize the application? Would that be possible or same behavior will occur?